# Converting my generic form variable into a specific type of form

Tags: c#, forms

I have a project which uses multiple forms, and the project may be running multiples of the same type. I am trying to write one class to manage all of my Forms, but I'm running into issue with types.

Obviously the generic class "Form" does not have some of the specific function I need to be able to call in my forms. What I want to be able to do is grab a form, check it's type, then call its type-specific functions. What I have set up for this is a switch-case, where I grab the string component of the type and then perform actions accordingly (I may clean that up later). The problem is, even when I know the type, I can't reassign my "Form" variable to a "TextEdit" variable. It says

"Cannot implicitly convert type "System.Windows.Forms.Form" to "GeFoss.TextEdit". An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Which leads me to believe that there is a way to do the transfer, but I am having trouble finding it. I don't know if I've left this unclear, but if you have questions let me know.

Here is the related code. Note that Process.initialize([[Form]]) is called immediately after the creation of Process in the main code

```
 public class Process
{

    public Form myFORM = new Form();
    public Type mytype;
.
.
.
.
    public void initialize(Form genMe)
    {
        myFORM = genMe;
        mytype = myFORM.GetType();
        giveProc();
    }
    private void giveProc()
    {
        switch (Convert.ToString(mytype))
        {
            case "GeFoss.TextEdit":
                TextEdit temp = myFORM;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast it to the type you want as it says in the message, the syntax for the cast looks like this:

```
 GeFoss.TextEdit temp = (GeFoss.TextEdit)myFORM;
```

NB - Casting can cause a run-time exception (not in this case with the switch statement).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I'd vote you up, but apparently I need 15 reputation for such things